# rvest webscrape in R

Tags: r, rvest

Having an issue scraping the site for the desired results. This page [SBR.com](https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/) has Todays date and Tomorrows date. I am trying get only today's date which I set as a value `date_data` However I get all content on the page. Also the `pinnacle_data` is not returning. I can see by inspecting the page that its there but rvest with SelectorGadget doesnt seem to retrieve it. I can return the other data but not that one.

**Desired Result**

Date | Time | Team | Opener | Pinnacle | 5 Dimes

**Code so far:**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)

# Get Website
url <- paste0('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/')
webpage <- read_html(url)

# date
date_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'._2NwoU ._3rOGQ span')
date_data <- html_text(date_data_html)

date <- data.frame(Date = date_data)

#TEAM
team_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'._1ekCo')
team_data <- html_text(team_data_html)

#opener
opener_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'._2cc9d span')
opener_data <- html_text(opener_data_html)

#time
time_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'._1t1eJ div:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)')
time_data <- html_text(time_data_html)

# pinnacle
pinnacle_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.slick-active:nth-child(2) span')
pinnacle_data <- html_text(pinnacle_data_html)

roster <- data.frame(TIME = time_data, TEAM = team_data, OPENER = opener_data, PINNACLE = pinnacle_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the table with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/")
Sys.sleep(10)
list_Tables <- list()

for(i in 1 : 11)
{
  print(i)
  web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", paste0("//*[@id='bettingOddsGridContainer']/div[3]/div[", 4 + (i - 1) * 2, "]")) 
  list_Tables[[i]] <- str_split(web_Obj$getElementText()[[1]], "\\n")[[1]]
  list_Tables[[i]] <- list_Tables[[i]][list_Tables[[i]] != "|"]
  nb_Col <- length(list_Tables[[i]]) / 2
  list_Tables[[i]] <- matrix(list_Tables[[i]], nrow = 2, ncol = nb_Col, byrow = FALSE)
  team_Name <- list_Tables[[i]][2, 2 : 3]
  team_Number <- list_Tables[[i]][1, 2 : 3]
  list_Tables[[i]][, 2] <- team_Name
  list_Tables[[i]][, 3] <- team_Number
  
  if(nb_Col == 15)
  {
    list_Tables[[i]] <- list_Tables[[i]][, -(4 : 7)]
  }
}

df_Table <- do.call("rbind", list_Tables)
df_Table
```